# Mod rewrite : Slashes in url cause strange behavior (Windows XP / WAMP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Just when I thought that I was starting to understand mod rewrite, I've discovered two problems which, although different, I suspect to have the same cause.
I'll post them separately - this is the first problem:

I have a localhost site. All the files (including .htaccess) are in the same directory.

I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^mytest/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ companies.php?page=$1 [L]
```

I have a menu link:

```
<a href="mytest/ibm" title="My test.... etc.
```

When I click on the link I connect to :

```
localhost/Mysite/mytest/ibm
```

which corresponds to the page companies.php containing information about IBM. So far so good.  The problem is that when I am in the "mytest" page and I hover over the same menu link I see :

```
localhost/Mysite/mytest/mytest/ibm
```

Which of course leads to a 404 error.

The question is: where is this extra "mytest" coming from ?

I've modified the rule in all the senses (or at least it seems to me that I have) without success.  I've no doute overlooked something simple - but what exactly ?

Comment: the problem is not in your `RewriteRule` its in the code of your page you need to post that for us to help

Comment: It sounds more like you have an issue with relative links than with your RewriteRule

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed due to an issue with relative links.
In changing to rewritten URLs I replaced the old :

```
<li><strong><a href="companies.php?page=companies" title="Company histories organized by….
```

By the new :

```
<li><strong><a href="company/list" title=" Company histories organized by….
```

The site had worked just fine up to this point  and since I had been tearing my hair out for 2 days trying to get my rewritten URLs to work IT HAD TO BE  mod rewrite that was responsible.

What I had overlooked was that the menu file was in an include folder.

Thanks to miah’s suggestion I took a step back and re-orientated my research towards relative links and found that the addition of this line:

```
<base href="http://localhost/Mysite/"></base>
```

at the top of my menu.php file solved my problem.

Life is so simple.  When it works…